# What is the use of systemd user instance for ssh logins

Tags: ssh, systemd, rhel

When you login using SSH, *pam_systemd* module automatically launches a *systemd --user* instance when the user logs in for the first time. We can mask the user@.service to deactivate this. Even when we deactivate the user@.service, there is no noticeable impact.

Is there a impact when we mask the service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disable` and `mask` are different things.

- `disable` means the `[Install]` section of a unit is ignored.  This typically means `WantedBy=multi-user.target` will be ignored, preventing the unit from starting on boot.
- `mask` means the unit cannot be activated.  That includes when another unit `Wants=` it, or even if you try to start it manually.  `mask`ing will certainly prevent `user@.service` from starting.

When you `sudo systemctl mask user@.service`, you are disabling the `--user` bus of `systemd`.  `unmask` and `start` the unit, then see `systemctl --user status` to see what will be unavailable.

On my desktop with a desktop environment, this looks something like:

```
$ systemctl --user status
● desktop
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Sun 2022-02-13 13:09:28 CET; 3 days ago
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service
           ├─app.slice
           │ ├─at-spi-dbus-bus.service
           │ ├─dbus.service
           │ ├─dconf.service
           │ ├─dunst.service
           │ ├─gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service
           │ ├─gvfs-daemon.service
           │ ├─gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service
           │ ├─gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service
           │ ├─gvfs-metadata.service
           │ ├─gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service
           │ ├─gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service
           │ ├─vnc.service
           │ ├─xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service
           │ ├─xdg-desktop-portal-gtk.service
           │ └─xdg-permission-store.service
           ├─background.slice
           │ ├─plasma-kglobalaccel.service
           │ └─tracker-miner-fs-3.service
           ├─init.scope
           └─session.slice
             ├─pipewire-media-session.service
             ├─pipewire.service
             ├─pulseaudio.service
             ├─xdg-desktop-portal.service
             └─xdg-document-portal.service
```

On a headless server with no desktop environment, this includes effectively nothing.

```
$ systemctl --user status
● server
    State: running
     Jobs: 0 queued
   Failed: 0 units
    Since: Wed 2022-02-16 13:29:30 CET; 3s ago
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service
           └─init.scope
             ├─581 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
             └─583 (sd-pam)
```

If I were to `systemctl mask user@.service`:

- On my desktop, many of these things are installed by my desktop environment.  I'll notice things like desktop-integrated authentication agents and notifications will stop working.  My VNC service will not be available, my USB sticks will not auto-mount, my keyrings will be unavailable, etc.
- On my server, I won't notice anything at all (not even a performance gain, as all processes listed are just idling.

In both cases, I'll loose the ability to define user-bus units if I need them.  `user` units can be useful for things like:

- Running backup scripts
- Mounting user-owned file-systems
- Running scripts in response to changes in files/directories

---

Edit: I almost forgot about some mounts.  `systemd` create `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` when a user logs in.  If you mask `user@.service`, that runtime user directory will not be created on login.  Anything that depends on it may have a problem.

See `systemctl --user list-units` for more units that get loaded on the user bus.

Comment: I have updated the wording of the question and removed the word disable.